# Need guidance with Finite State Machine

Tags: c

I need some help with changing the states in Finite state machine. The structure for my state machine is as follows:

```
typedef struct stateMachine {

    char name;
    struct stateMachine *next0;
    struct stateMachine *next1;
}stateMac,*stateMac_p;

static stateMac_p current_state;
```

where i was thinking to use *stateMac_p to point the current state of state machine. next0 is the current state when 0 is entered and next1 is current state when 1 is entered by user. Say a sample state table is given below:

```
A B C

B C D

C D A
```

I have implemented a state machine and I initialized the states using following code:

```
{
    int i=0;

    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
        fsm[i].name=i+65;
    fsm[0].next0=(&(fsm[1]));
    fsm[0].next1=(&(fsm[2]));
    fsm[1].next0=(&(fsm[2]));
    fsm[1].next1=(&(fsm[3]));
    fsm[2].next0=(&(fsm[3]));
    fsm[2].next1=(&(fsm[0]));

//... and so on

    current_state = fsm[2].name;
}
```

When program is executed, it first prints the state of current state and waits for user input. My question is how can I change the states in main? For example, if 0 is pressed, it should change the current state to D. Or if 1 is pressed it should change the state to A based on current state C and D A as next states.
I am trying to accomplish it as follows but it gives me error.

```
case '0':
    current_state=current_state->next0;
    printf("The current state now is %c\n",current_state);
```

and so on for case '1'.

The code compiles but When 0 is pressed, **the program crashes**. Please help with changing states.

Comment: "gives an error?", "crashes"? More details, please. And, probably you want to print `current_state->name` rather than `current_state`

Comment: I think `printf("The current state now is %c\n",current_state);` should be `printf("The current state now is %c\n",current_state->name);`

Comment: @Rav You've almost got a complete set of code in the question, but you're missing some key pieces. I suggest that you edit the question and provide a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: what's the type of `current_state`?

Comment: @EugeneSh.
Thank you for your comment. I forgot to add in my code that I have declared a static pointer type:

static stateMac_p current_state;

When I press 0 the program crashes. 

As per your suggestion current_state->name doesn't fix the issue and the program crashes as well.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr

static stateMac_p current_state;

Comment: `current_state = fsm[2].name;` it's a wrong assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpret your code right then I would assume the following:

1. Change the assignment as follows: `current_state = &(fsm[2]);`. I think you want to point to a state and not to the name of a state.
2. It should be `printf("The current state now is %c\n",current_state->name);`.

You could also define the structure like this and avoid the need for a switch statement:

```
typedef struct stateMachine {
  char name;
  struct stateMachine *next[2];
} stateMac, *stateMac_p;
```

Next state (assuming a valid input character `c`):

```
current_state = current_state->next[c-48];
```

Comment: Thank you very Much for your assistance on this @user0815.
I followed your suggestions and my code worked as per my expectations.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Since `current_state` is assigned a `name`, it appears to be a `char`.  But in the `switch` it is used as if it were a pointer to a `stateMachine`.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a enum for states

e.g

```
typedef enum {STATE_1 = 0, ..., WHATEVER_NAME_YOU_WANT, ...} States
```

These are essentially integers.

Then write a function to convert the input into an integer from 0 to n.

e.g.

```
int Convert(char c) { return c - 'A'; };
```

Then the FSM just is a 2D array. Some elements will never get to see the light of day

For example

```
typedef char Input; // Or whatever type for the input
```

To change from one state to another do (for example)

```
State FSM[][] = {
  { STATE_1, STATE_2 },
  { FINAL, NO_REACHED }
};
```

Then to run it do:

state = STATE_1;
   while (state != FINAL) {
      state = FSM[state][ConvertInput()];
   }

If you had ConvertInput in this example converts A->0, B->1

Then this will recognize A*B in terms of regular expressions

But to give them names - Just convert the integers for the states to a human readable format.